# Saving form data rewrites the same row

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, save, django-views

i can't figure out how to save my form data creating a new row, when saving it just rewrites the data using the same 'id' and trhows me an error when there are multiple rows, this is my code:

**models.py:**

```
class Submitter(models.Model):
    submitter=models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.submitter.username

class Store(models.Model):
    creator=models.ForeignKey(Submitter)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'),blank=True,max_length=30)
    st = models.CharField(_('Street'),blank=True,max_length=30)
    sub_date = models.DateField(_('Visit Date'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s-%s-%s'%(self.creator,self.name,self.sub_date)
```

**views.py:**

```
def StoreSave(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StoreForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            submitter, dummy= Creator.objects.get_or_create(creator=request.user)
            store, created = Store.objects.get_or_create(
                submitter=submitter
            )
            store.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            store.st = form.cleaned_data['st']
            store.visit_date = form.cleaned_data['visit_date']
            store.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/%s/' % request.user.username)
    else:
        form = StoreForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
    })
    return render_to_response('store/create_store.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a new row, create it. :-) Like

```
store = Store(submitter=submitter,
              name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
              st=form.cleaned_data['st'],
              store.visit_date=form.cleaned_data['visit_date'])
store.save()
```

Now you use `get_or_create` method which tries to find a row with given parameters, so that's why you updating it. And this method throws an error when there are multiple rows, yes, it's its normal behavior.

By the way it's better to place this saving code in form's method (`save` for example).

P. S. Just noticed you don't have `visit_date` field in your model, I think you meant `sub_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `get_or_create` you can simply use `create`

```
Store.objects.create(
    submitter=submitter,
    name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
    st=form.cleaned_data['st'],
    visit_date=form.cleaned_data['visit_date']
)
```

More information about the differences can be found [Django Model() vs Model.objects.create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create)