# Django Model() vs Model.objects.create()

Tags: python, django, django-models

What it the difference between running two commands:

```
foo = FooModel()
```

and

```
bar = BarModel.objects.create()
```

Does the second one immediately create a `BarModel` in the database, while for `FooModel`, the `save()` method has to be called explicitly to add it to the database?

Comment: Yes, that is the difference.

Comment: Is it always true? I've seen places in Django documentation where they call save() on an instance after creating it via *.objects.create(). Like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @Aleksandr Mikheev : I don't see `.save()` after none from 40 text occurences of `create` there. If you want tell something, then please post a link which leads to short code example, not to 10 pages of text. Why do you make the others unsure without a strong reason for that?

Comment: For clarity, save() also works on created objects. If you make a change to an object, you will still need to call save() to record those changes to the database.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects

> To create and save an object in a single step, use the `create()` method.

Comment: The django docs are a bit contradictory on this point in my opinion. I've had the same question and read "Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database; for that, you need to save()." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

Comment: I don't see that as contradictory. Generally in python, You instantiate objects by putting brackets after the Objects name not by a create method

Comment: @danidee I agree it is not contradictory, but it is certainly misleading. Mainly because in Nils 's link, example1 is "instantiating" but example2 is "instantiating+saving".
Also, why should I refer to "queries" doc when I want to know how to save a model? There are really a lot of pains in django doc.

Comment: @Nakamura because INSERT is a query?

Comment: @madzohan I think the docs changed to the exact opposite: "To create an object, instantiate it using keyword arguments to the model class, then call save() to save it to the database."

Comment: It would be nice to point out what the difference between `Model.objects.create(...)` and `obj = Model(); obj.save()` is.

Comment: @MartinThoma actually nothing was changed, use `Ctrl+F` with the cite from my answer ... BTW don't upvote it, I mean seriously, guys - just read that awesome docs :) Peace!

Answer (score 65):

The differences between `Model()` and `Model.objects.create()` are the following:

---

1. INSERT vs UPDATE

   `Model.save()` does either INSERT or UPDATE of an object in a DB, while `Model.objects.create()` does only INSERT.

   `Model.save()` does

   - **UPDATE** If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates to `True`
   - **INSERT** If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything (e.g. if primary key is set to a value that doesn’t exist in the database).

---

2. Existing primary key

   If primary key attribute is set to a value and such primary key already exists, then `Model.save()` performs UPDATE, but `Model.objects.create()` raises `IntegrityError`.

   Consider the following *models.py:*

   ```
   class Subject(models.Model):
      subject_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='subject_id')
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      max_marks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   ```

   1. Insert/Update to db with `Model.save()`

      ```
      physics = Subject(subject_id=1, name='Physics', max_marks=100)
      physics.save()
      math = Subject(subject_id=1, name='Math', max_marks=50)  # Case of update
      math.save()
      ```

      Result:

      ```
      Subject.objects.all().values()
      <QuerySet [{'subject_id': 1, 'name': 'Math', 'max_marks': 50}]>
      ```
   2. Insert to db with `Model.objects.create()`

      ```
      Subject.objects.create(subject_id=1, name='Chemistry', max_marks=100)
      IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: m****t.subject_id
      ```

   **Explanation:** In the example, `math.save()` does an UPDATE (changes `name` from *Physics* to *Math*, and `max_marks` from 100 to 50), because `subject_id` is a primary key and `subject_id=1` already exists in the DB. But `Subject.objects.create()` raises `IntegrityError`, because, again the primary key `subject_id` with the value `1` already exists.

---

3. Forced insert

   `Model.save()` can be made to behave as `Model.objects.create()` by using `force_insert=True` parameter: `Model.save(force_insert=True)`.

---

4. Return value

   `Model.save()` return `None` where `Model.objects.create()` return model instance i.e. `package_name.models.Model`

---

**Conclusion:** `Model.objects.create()` does model initialization and performs `save()` with `force_insert=True`.

Excerpt from the source code of `Model.objects.create()`

```
def create(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
    and returning the created object.
    """
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    self._for_write = True
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    return obj
```

For more details follow the links:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create
2. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2d8dcba03aae200aaa103ec1e69f0a0038ec2f85/django/db/models/query.py#L440

Comment: This is much better and more helpful than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

The two syntaxes are not equivalent and it can lead to unexpected errors.
Here is a simple example showing the differences.
If you have a model:

```
from django.db import models

class Test(models.Model):

    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And you create a first object:

```
foo = Test.objects.create(pk=1)
```

Then you try to create an object with the same primary key:

```
foo_duplicate = Test.objects.create(pk=1)
# returns the error:
# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")

foo_duplicate = Test(pk=1).save()
# returns the error:
# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'added' cannot be null")
```

Comment: so `.create()` creates an object even if an required field(`null=False`) is missing?
I am adding tests to my project and `create` is having unexpected results

Comment: No, it should not... Though some field types act a bit weird in Django.
For example, `CharField` even if set to `null=False` will not raise an error if not provided: this is because Django set strings by default to an empty string `""` so it is not technically `null`

Comment: yeah, I am having problems only with char fields and field field(which is basically char field too). Using `obj = MyModel()`, then `obj.full_clean()` for now.

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE 15.3.2017:

I have opened a Django-issue on this and it seems to be preliminary accepted here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27825

My experience is that when using the `Constructor` (`ORM`) class by references with Django `1.10.5` there might be some inconsistencies in the data (i.e. the attributes of the created object may get the type of the input data instead of the casted type of the ORM object property)
example:

`models`

```
class Payment(models.Model):
     amount_cash = models.DecimalField()
```

`some_test.py` - `object.create`

```
Class SomeTestCase:
    def generate_orm_obj(self, _constructor, base_data=None, modifiers=None):
        objs = []
        if not base_data:
            base_data = {'amount_case': 123.00}
        for modifier in modifiers:
            actual_data = deepcopy(base_data)
            actual_data.update(modifier)
            # Hacky fix,
            _obj = _constructor.objects.create(**actual_data)
            print(type(_obj.amount_cash)) # Decimal
            assert created
           objs.append(_obj)
        return objs
```

`some_test.py` - `Constructor()`

```
Class SomeTestCase:
    def generate_orm_obj(self, _constructor, base_data=None, modifiers=None):
        objs = []
        if not base_data:
            base_data = {'amount_case': 123.00}
        for modifier in modifiers:
            actual_data = deepcopy(base_data)
            actual_data.update(modifier)
            # Hacky fix,
            _obj = _constructor(**actual_data)
            print(type(_obj.amount_cash)) # Float
            assert created
           objs.append(_obj)
        return objs
```

Comment: Josh Smeaton gave an [excellent answer](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27825#comment:9) regarding developer own responsibility to cast types. Please, update your answer.

Answer (score 7):

`Model.objects.create()` creates a model instance and saves it. `Model()` only creates an in memory model instance. It's not saved to the database until you call the instance's `save()` method to save it. That's when validation happens also.

Comment: What is the benefit of either?

Comment: @VaidøtasI- You can use Model.objects.using('database').create() in the second one. This comes in handy if you have multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `Model()` to create model instances you would want to use right away. You don’t want to store these in a backup store (database or file) probably because of latency or what not. You could cache though ([as static variables <sup>[Stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566667/16770846) for example)
- Use `Model.objects.create()` to create something and store right away in some database somewhere.

---

> Does the second one immediately create a BarModel in the database, while for FooModel, the save() method has to be called explicitly to add it to the database?

**Exactly right!**