# How do I create an instance of a model in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm having trouble finding out how to create a new instance of a model inside the views.

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create), I tried doing

```
foo = FooModel()
save()
```

but I got a NameError: name 'save' is not defined. 
I then tried

```
bar = BarModel.objects.create()
```

but got AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'Create'.

Am I not understanding something very trivial? Maybe those commands are just for the command line? In that case, how do I create new objects, or filter them, etc... from code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first example, you need to call the save method on the object, e.g. `foo.save()` instead of just `save()`:

```
foo = FooModel()
foo.save()
```

Your second example looks ok. Make sure you are calling `create()` (all lowercase):

```
bar = BarModel.objects.create()
```

The message `... no attribute 'Create'.` suggests you are calling `BarModel.objects.Create()`, which is incorrect.

If that still doesn't work, then update your question with the actual code and full traceback. Using made up names like `FooModel` makes it harder to see the problem.

Comment: If I do the second way, will any parameter I specify for that object be automatically saved?

Like if I do `bar.name='emerald' #implying the model has an attribute name`

Comment: `bar.name='emerald'` just sets the attribute. It won’t be saved to the database until you call `bar.save()`. However you can do `bar = BarModel.objects.create(name='emerald')` to create and save an object with that name.

Comment: I did the second thing you suggested in the end, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`save` is method of instance, should be:

```
foo = FooModel()
foo.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new instance of a object from your models you do like that:

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
test = Test()
```

You can also use the constructor:

```
test = Test(id=3)
test.save() # save object to database
test.objects.filter(id=3) # get object from database
```

Comment: `Test(id=3)` isn’t a good example - usually you should let the database set the primary key automatically.