# django Model.objects.create not immediately assign primary key to variable how to access that?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have django `Student` model like below

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Student(id: {self.id}, name: {self.name}, salary: {self.score})"
```

I have created some users in database also below is `django shell` output

```
>>> s = Student.objects.create(name="erik", score=90)
>>> print(s)
Student(id: None, name: erik, salary: 90)   # <----- here is showing id None
>>> Student.objects.all()                                                                                                       
<QuerySet [<Student: Student(id: 1, name: alex, salary: 40.00)>, <Student: Student(id: 2, name: john, salary: 60.00)>, <Student: Student(id: 3, name: erik, salary: 90.00)>]>
```

when i have called `Student.objects.all()` then it is showing id.

I want to get `id` from `s` variable because i am performing unit testing like below.

```py
class GetSingleStudentTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Student.objects.create(name="student1", score=50)
        Student.objects.create(name="student2", score=55)
        Student.objects.create(name="student3", score=80)
        Student.objects.create(name="student4", score=36)

    def test_get_single_student(self):
        # get API response
        response = client.get(reverse("student-detail", kwargs={"pk" : self.student2.pk }))

        # get data from db
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=self.student2.pk)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(student)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

So when i have tried to access `self.student2.pk` it is `None` like we saw in `django shell` also. So how can i get that `id`?

because as i know `Model.objects.create` creates a user and also save into database then why `id` is `None` here? I am learning from this guide https://realpython.com/test-driven-development-of-a-django-restful-api/ but they not showed this kind of issues that's why I asked here. I have used `setUpTestData` method also but same kind of issue is there.

I think `AutoField` is working perfectly. Is it same as `IntegerField` but i have specified `primary_key=True`.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you add that `id` field later? I assume you didn't have that field declared on your model at the start and later added it (and didn't run `makemigrations` and `migrate` either) Otherwise I don't know how you are _not getting an error_.

Comment: You are not assigning anything to the id, its just a primary key. If you are expecting autoincrement, use `AutoField ` instead of IntegerField.
Also im confuse how it is showing for queryset then.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No i did't add it later and i also have done migrations at first.

Comment: @Summer you are absolutely right thanks.

Comment: I suggest you remove the manual field `id = ...` in your model. Django then generates automatically a field called `id` which is the primary key with auto increment set to True.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `save()` the object so that pk is assigned. Also, you may refer to official doc at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys

Comment: I think `create` method is used to `create and save` object in single step. I have read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672077/django-model-vs-model-objects-create

Comment: hi @Visrut you are probably right.